# css media query max-device-width

Tags: css, media-queries

If I have css 3 media query for max-device-width does this change when the orientation of the device changes?

For example if an iPhone goes from portrait to landscape does the max-device-width change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This differs from iPhone, iPad etc to other devices. With Apple products, the `device-width` values remain the same, but with other devices changing the orientation could cause alternative rules to apply.

The most reliable way to do this is to use `min`/`max-width` instead of `min`/`max-device-width`. These are dependent on the size of the viewport, and are consistent across devices.

Comment: Are you staying that max-device-width is not reliable on other platforms and are recommending NOT to use this? What is your source for this information?

Comment: @ChrisMuench I am saying `max-device-width` is not consistent across devices when looking at orientation changes. With iPad, iPhone etc, orientation changes do not affect the `device-width`, whereas with other devices this is the case. My source for this is experience, you can test it yourself if you make a page and try orientation changes on an iPad and a Kindle.

Comment: Got it, thats the way I understood device-width also. It is a constant no matter what the orientation is, but different between devices.

Comment: @ChrisMuench I think I might have miscommunicated a bit. The `device-width` is **only** constant on the iPad, iPhone. Regardless of which way you turn an Apple device, the `device-width` is the same. On other devices, however, it changes when you change the orientation of the device.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt change the orientation

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
/* Portrait styles */
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
/* Landscape styles */
}
```

Comment: *The useful thing about **device-width** in the viewport meta tag is that it updates when the user changes the orientation of their smartphone or tablet.* [Google Webmaster Central](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2012/04/responsive-design-harnessing-power-of.html)